# How do I integrate a Xamarin forms app with Azure Directline speech bot?

Tags: azure, xamarin, botframework, speech, direct-line-botframework

Good day guys,
I have a bot built on the azure bot framework and have enabled the direct line speech channel.
I have a xamarin forms client that communicates with the bot and is able to receive text responses from the bot.
I am unable to play the raw audio responses from the bot. Does anyone have experience doing this?
I'd really appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Code sample below

```cs
private void Connector_ActivityReceived
(object sender, ActivityReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var json = e.Activity;
        var activity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(json);
        
        if (e.HasAudio && activity.Speak != null)
        { 
           var audio = e.Audio; // How do I play the contents of e.Audio in xamarin forms?
        }
```

Comment: what format are the "raw audio responses from the bot" in?

Comment: Hi Jason, the format of the raw audio response is a PullAudioOutputStream object. I'm editing the issue details on this post as well to show a code sample. Thanks!

Comment: Does the [Cognitive Services Voice Assistant](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Voice-Assistant) sample help? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney. Thanks for your comment. The Cognitive Services Voice Assistant samples do help to a large extent. However, they have examples for UWP, .net core, and some other languages. Nothing exists for Xamarin Forms

Comment: Hi @Jason.  the format of the raw audio response is a PullAudioOutputStream object. I'm editing the issue details on this post as well to show a code sample. Thanks!

Comment: @AFAMEFUNAMILLAINEANIGBO - Have a look at the UWP sample. It's in C# just like Xamarin and it shows how to use the PullAudioOutputStream class.

Comment: Thanks @KyleDelaney - Indeed the samples show how to use the PullAudioOutputStream Class. The issue is not to play the audio stream content of this class in a xamarin forms app. Playing audio on a device running the windows OS is very different from playing on a device running android or ios. So I guess my ask is more of a Xamarin Forms technicality - than a Bot Framework one... :-(

Comment: @AFAMEFUNAMILLAINEANIGBO - How about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-audio

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation description, PullAudioOutputStream represents a memory backed pull audio output stream. Having a stream with the audio data, you can use something like a cross-platform audio player to play it back:

```
var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
audio.Load(stream );
audio.Play();
```

Example found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/170646/how-to-play-audio-in-xamarin-forms).

The CrossSimpleAudioPlayer is just an abstraction over native iOS/Android functionality for audio playback, and if you have other preferred ways to implement it natively, you can use [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to inject it and use it in your cross-platform Xamarin.Forms core code.